# QueryMultiple in Dapper only showing the first list

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-core, dapper

I'm using dapper to try and send multiple querys at the same time. I have 2 different querys that I want to use. However, no matter what I try, I can only get the method to find 1 of the querys.

Firstly, here's the controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Test(RequestOverview model)
{

    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }
    try
    {
        await _request.Test(model);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        return BadRequest(ex.Message);
    }
    return Ok();
}
```

Interface:

```
Task<bool> Test(RequestOverview model);
```

Model:

```
public class TestT
{
    public string vehicleRegNr { get; set; } = "";
}

public class TestE
{
    public string dealerName { get; set; } = "";
}
```

Sidenote: The name of the entire class is `RequestOverview`

Now, here are some of my attempts in the method that uses dapper:

```
// attempt 1
public async Task<bool> Test(RequestOverview model)
{

    string query = @"SELECT TOP 5 RegNumber as vehicleRegNr FROM [dbo].[Vehicle]; 
                     SELECT TOP 5 Retailer.Name as dealerName FROM [dbo].[Retailer]";

    using (var multi = _sqlconnection.QueryMultiple(query, null))
    {
        List<TestT> list1 = multi.Read<TestT>().AsList();
        List<TestE> list2 = multi.Read<TestE>().AsList();
    }

    return true;
}



attempt 2//
public async Task<bool> Test(TestT model)
{
    string query = @"SELECT TOP 5 RegNumber as vehicleRegNr FROM [dbo].[Vehicle]; 
                     SELECT TOP 5 Retailer.Name as dealerName FROM [dbo].[Retailer]";

    using (var multi = _sqlconnection.QueryMultiple(query, null))
    {
        List<dynamic> list1 = multi.Read<dynamic>().AsList();
        List<dynamic> list2 = multi.Read<dynamic>().AsList();
    }

    return true;
}
```

(In attempt 2 I use only one model class `TestT` that has `vehicleRegNr` and `dealerName` as parameters)

However, no matter what I get this output when debugging:
[image]

List 2 always ends up null, anyone knows why?
Thankful for help.
(Sidenote: List 1 contains the `vehicleRegNr`)

Comment: Sorry but I could not reproduce that problem. See https://dotnetfiddle.net/j0L0kd here, it works as expected.

Comment: Are you sure that you check list2 values after `multi.Read<dynamic>().AsList();` executed :) ?

Comment: Or maybe the second query returns nothing?

Comment: thank you @SelimYildiz, i don't know what the problem was but i changed to your example and it works great now! :)

Comment: You are welcome, glad it worked. I have also added it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could not reproduce that problem, created an example https://dotnetfiddle.net/j0L0kd and `QueryMultiple` works as expected.

And you can see the results:
[image]

So I suspect either you check `list2` values before `multi.Read<dynamic>().AsList();` executed or second query returns nothing :)